# What is the right regression model if the dependent variable is a percentage?

Tags: r, regression, modeling, percentage

I have a database where I have a population divided by income percentiles. For each percentile, I have data about the average income, and the percentage of children that attend at least some college between age 18-21. 
I would like to have a model that, for a given income, tells me what percentage of children I can expect to attend college. Problem is, since the dependent variable is a percentage, with a linear regression I get predicted values like 150% of kids going to college for a very high income. I've tried with the betareg package 
`betareg(formula = college ~ par_fam_inc, data = unis)` 
but it returns "model did not converge".

Does anybody know how to help me with this?

Thanks a lot, and sorry, I'm just a beginner with R.

Pietro

edit: an example of the data I have. Yearly parents' income in par_fam_inc, college attendance of chldren in college.

[image]

Comment: betareg is a good solution. If you give us more information about your data (hopefully a [mcve]) we might be able to help you understand why the model didn't converge.  You should scale your data so that the values are in the interval (0,1). (not 0-100) ...

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. i added a picture with the kind of data I have.

Comment: Scaling the income data to units of thousands, a 2nd order (quadratic) polynomial fit as well as a 3rd or 4th order polynomial.

Comment: Can you (1) include your data example as text (cut-and-paste rather than including a screenshot); (2) edit your question to include the exact output and warning/error messages?